# first page of printindex index not using fancy style

Tags: fancyhdr, imakeidx

When working with something like this MWE I found that the first page of the index, *despite* using `firstpagestyle=fancy` the index is showing the page number in the center.

## Problem: index not using fancy style

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[index]{kantlipsum}
\makeindex
\indexsetup
 { firstpagestyle=fancy
 , othercode={\thispagestyle{fancy}}
 }

\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem Ipsum}

\kant[1-200]

\printindex

\end{document}
```

## Solution: don't use `twocolumn`

After 3 days of googlinge and boiling down my code to this MnWE I found that the culprit is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
```

when I change it to

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
```

and use the `multicol` package to do the column layout for the document it works.

## Now my question: Why does a `documenclass`' option does affect the layout of the index/fancyhdr?

Comment: With `\twocolumn` it activates the option `original`, and that disables `\indexsetup`. You can leave out the documentclass option and add `\twocolumn` at the beginning of the document, but then you get a 4-column index, unless you use `\onecolumn` before `\printindex`.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum that does not sound like a comment but an answer => Could you put that into one so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `\twocolumn` it activates the option `original`, and that disables `\indexsetup`. You can leave out the documentclass option and add `\twocolumn` at the beginning of the document, but then you get a 4-column index, unless you use `\onecolumn` before `\printindex`.